# Linux: how to automatically restart service if there is error in log?

Tags: linux, services, systemctl

Hello in the `sudo systemctl status <service>` I sometimes see an error in text like `[info] asio async_shutdown error: asio.system:32 (Broken pipe)`, yet it is still marked as [info] and status of service is `active (running)`.

I need to monitor the service log and if there is a word `error` in the log I need to issue `sudo systemctl restart <service>`. Is that possible?

Comment: this is definitely possible. there are a number of log watchers for linux out there that you can use, or even just use tail in a chron job like `tail -f some-logfile | awk '/some-pattern/ {system("run-some-command")}'` . it will require some scripting, but is entirely possible.

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it did not do anything. I tried to add second sudo but it did not help: `sudo journalctl -f -u ifi-streamer-tidal-connect.service | awk '/Max connection attempts/ {system("systemctl restart ifi-streamer-tidal-connect.service")}'`

Comment: have you verified that the journalctl command is producing output that awk can parse?

Comment: Yes for example this is the line that should trigger service restart: `Feb 03 15:04:54 tidal-pi tidal_connect_application[21553]: [2022-02-03 15:04:54.239] [tisoc] [warning] [logger.cpp:22] [audio_worker.cpp:288] Max connection attempts reached!
`

Comment: I believe the problem is that Journalctl is buffering output, since it doesn't exit, so the pipe is never getting the input. try adding the `--no-pager` option to your journalctl command.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by running following command every 5 seconds in a loop:

```
journalctl -n 10 -u ifi-streamer-tidal-connect.service | grep -i "Max connection attempts" && sudo systemctl restart ifi-streamer-tidal-connect.service
```

Comment: glad you got it working. I'm a little surprised that grep has a different exit code for when it found somthing than when it didn't. that's neat! you can replace your loop with a cron job if you don't want to manually restart the script after reboots. that will also help if the command crashes every once in a while. you may want to watch to make sure it doesn't react to the same log entry more than once though.

Comment: I avoid the duplicate run by limiting number of lines. Restart produces about 20 lines of log, so I am sure that after restart there is no error message anymore.